# CakePHP Paginator->sort(__d( does not work

Tags: cakephp, plugins, paginator

I have a plugin translated with i18n, In `index.ctp` there is the paginator sort:

`<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(__d('item', 'item_layout_id')); ?>`

When I try to sort the columns, they are not put in order.

This is the url with i18n:

`index/sort:Layout/direction:desc`

instead of:

`index/sort:item_layout_id/direction:desc`

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are using the `sort` method of `paginator` helper is wrong, just try like this.

```
<?php $this->Paginator->sort('item_layout_id', __('item')); ?>
```

or

```
<?php $this->Paginator->sort('item_layout_id', __d('your_domain_name', 'item')); ?>
```

For more details, check [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#PaginatorHelper%3a%3asort).

Comment: In this way it works <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('item_layout_id', __d('survey','item_layout_id')); ?> thanks

Answer (score 0):

### You are only passing one argument to sort

[The sort function](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#creating-sort-links):

> PaginatorHelper::sort($key, $title = null, $options = array())

The code in the question is passing a variable fieldname to the sort function, it can be rewritten as:

```
<?php 
$translated = __d('item', 'item_layout_id');
echo $this->Paginator->sort($translated);
```

This will mean that *if* there is a translation for `item_layout_id` - the sort links will nolonger work as the field `Layout` (from the question) doesn't exist. Attempting to sort by a field that doesn't exist results in the parameter being ignored.

### Correct usage

To translate the title of a sort link - use the title parameter:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Paginator->sort(
    'item_layout_id', // Sort by this field
    __d('item', 'item_layout_id') // Display this text
);
```